# running ip4r query 'remotely'

Tags: postgresql

I have maxmind csv db loaded into a DB (aka 'global') that is to be shared by all my DB (say DBa, DBb, ..) on a given server. I can quite happily run an IP lookup query when connected to 'global' (and its nice and fast). But I want to be able to do a lookup when connected to a DBa. Ie I want a function iplookup that DBa can use like this

```
select size,name,iplookup(ipaddr) from widget
```

I can make this go by using ip4r directly having mapped the csv table in global as a foreign table to DBa. The problem is that it performs terribly (I assume its the overhead of the ip4r code runnning in the DBa connection, but the data being accessed remotely in the foreign global connection).

I think I need to query in such a way that the ip4r code is running in the global connection. Feels like I should be able to do some function and view defining to make that happen but can't work it out. I cant work out how to pass parameters to a view